# jQuery function doesn't recognize new image

Tags: jquery, image, dom

I have an image on my page. I also use a jQuery plugin to create a reflection effect on the image. The problem is when I change the image "src" attribute (using attr() jQuery function) to another image. The problem is that the plugin doesn't recognize the new image. Instead, it does a reflection on the old image. I think that the plugin doesn't recognize the changes in the DOM.

Do you know if there is a solution for this problem or how I would go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried applying the reflection again after you change the `src` attribute? If [this](http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery) is the reflection plugin you're using, you should be able to do:

```
$("#imageId").reflection();
```

The new reflection should replace the old reflection.